# How to replace one string of multiple file name

Tags: bash

I have many files like this

```
BBG-06-0645-01B.txt 
BFDG_06-0219-01T.txt    
MFD-02-0047-011T.txt
BBTF_06-0649-01N.txt    
BFGD_02-2486-016J.txt
```

I am trying to replace any hyphens with underscores, like the following

```
BBG_06_0645_01B.txt 
BFDG_06_0219_01T.txt    
MFD_02_0047_011T.txt
BBTF_06_0649_01N.txt    
BFGD_02_2486_016J.txt
```

I tried to use the following without sucecss

```
rename -nvs - _  *.txt
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s/\Q${\"\-"}/_/ }
'BBG-06-0645-01B.txt' would be renamed to 'BBG_06-0645-01B.txt'
'BBTF_06-0649-01N.txt' would be renamed to 'BBTF_06_0649-01N.txt'
'BFDG_06-0219-01T.txt' would be renamed to 'BFDG_06_0219-01T.txt'
'BFGD_02-2486-016J.txt' would be renamed to 'BFGD_02_2486-016J.txt'
'MFD-02-0047-011T.txt' would be renamed to 'MFD_02-0047-011T.txt'
```

if I also use `rename 's/\Q${\"\-"}/_/'  *.txt` it does not change - to _ for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rename` like this:

```
rename "s/-/_/g" *.txt
```

dry run with the `-n` flag:

```
rename -n "s/-/_/g" *.txt
```

**bash substitution with a for loop**:

```
for file in *.txt; do mv "$file" "${file//-/_}" ; done
```

dry run with `echo` instead of `mv`:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo "$file" "${file//-/_}" ; done
```

Comment: No offense please, since I saw you had added `tr` for substitution so I added  BASH substitution in my solution.(no code copy done here) :)  Thought to mention here so that no confusions.

Comment: Note: that if `rename` is provided by the `util-linux` package (as it is on many distributions) regular expressions are not supported as they are with `perl-rename`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I'm not exactly sure what you are implying.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure BASH substitution here. Could you please try following.(For dry run only)

```
for file in *.txt
do
    echo "mv $file ${file//-/_}"
done
```

This will only print the statements first, once you are happy with commands(`mv` commands) then remove `echo` from above command.

here is an example of output `mv BBG-06-0645-01B.txt BBG_06_0645_01B.txt`

Once you are happy with results above use following.

```
for file in *.txt
do
     echo "File named $file is going to rename to ${file//-/_}"
     mv "$file" "${file//-/_}"
done
```

In case you want to print status which file has been successfully renamed or not use:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    echo "File named $file is going to rename to ${file//-/_}"
    if mv "$file" "${file//-/_}"
    then
         echo "File named $file is successfully renamed to ${file//-/_}"
    else
         echo "Please check seems file $file did not rename."
    fi
done
```

Comment: it gives me this `mv  BBG-06-0645_01B.txt BBG-06-0645-01B.txt
mv  BBTF-06-0649_01N.txt BBTF-06-0649-01N.txt
mv  BFDG-06-0219_01T.txt BFDG-06-0219-01T.txt
mv  BFGD-02-2486_016J.txt BFGD-02-2486-016J.txt
mv  MFD-02-0047_011T.txt MFD-02-0047-011T.txt`

Comment: I want all of those `-` to become `_`

Comment: @Learner, correct as I mentioned it will print the commands which will be executed(once you remove `echo` from my code), verify them if they look good to you then remove `echo` from this code and it will rename the actual files.

Comment: @Learner, sorry thought that you need to only substitute last `-`, try above now and let me know?

Comment: I liked it , it was nice solution

Comment: Your examples do the opposite of what is supposed to happen; `$file` should go *before* `${file//-/_}` (switch it around)... you are trying to rename `this_file.txt` into `this-file.txt`.

Comment: @I'L'I, thanks a lot for letting me know for typo, I fixed it now. Thanks a TON.

Comment: @glenn jackman, thanks a TON Glenn for nice editing, happy weekend ahead.